# Require paths are not proper after typescript file was transpiled by babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

**Problem**

When I run a nodemon with *npm run start*, I get *Error: Cannot find module 'Test'*, and When I build files with *npm run build* and run ./dist/index.js, I get the same error.

As you can see, a require path on *./dist/index.js* is not recognized properly.

I don't know which configuration have to be changed, so I questioned.

If you know about that, Please reply back to me with your asnwer. Thanks :)

**Source Code**

./src/index.ts

```
import Test from 'Test';

const test = new Test();
```

./src/Test/index.ts

```
export default class Test {
    constructor () {
        console.log('Test');
    }
}
```

./dist/index.js

```
"use strict";

var _Test = _interopRequireDefault(require("Test"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var test = new _Test.default();
```

./package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel ./src --extensions .ts,.js --out-dir ./dist",
    "start": "nodemon ./src --exec babel-node --extensions .ts,.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.4"
  }
}
```

./tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": ["ES2015", "ES2017", "DOM"],
        "noEmit": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "paths": { "*":["node_modules/*", "src/*"] },
        "pretty": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
    }
}
```

./.babelrc

```
{
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
}
```

Comment: I've solved this problem using a module-alias pakage :D

Answer (score 2):

Try `import Test from './Test';` in your `./src/index.ts`. Because without relative path typescript looks for the global module `Test`. When you want to use local module you should use relative path to your module.

Comment: Thanks you :) Is there any other way to maintain the module path as Test? I use the *paths* setting to load like a global module because using relative paths is so complicated.

Comment: You can use `paths` so aliases for relative paths. [This article](https://goenning.net/2017/07/21/how-to-avoid-relative-path-hell-javascript-typescript-projects) can help you.

Comment: Thank you, But I think It seemed to be a setting that I did above.. *"paths": { "*":["node_modules/*", "src/*"] },*  I changed that setting to *"paths": { "*":["node_modules/*"], "@app/*":["src/*"] },* and use *import Test from '@app/Test';*, but I got the same *Error: Cannot find module '@app/Test'*.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help! I get the same error(Error: Cannot find module 'Test') after I change it as you say. (That answer seems to have been deleted now.)